# Can SonarLint scan the as and mxml files of Flex?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I use SonarLint with connected mode with my sonarQube instance, I installed the flex plugin, here is a picuture :

[image]

I synchronized my Sonarlint Server but I can't have detail of the analysis. I right click on my as/mxml files> SonarLint > Analysis , but nothing is displayed on Eclipse. 
I'm using Sonar-runner since my jenkins job, here is the property file I defined:

```
sonar.host.url=http://host/sonar
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectKey= myKey
sonar.projectVersion=v0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/*
sonar.exclusions=**/*.class,**/*.project,**/target/**,**/*.log,**/*.jar,**/*.png,**/*.jpg,**/*.jpeg,**/.sonar/**,sonar-project.properties,**/*.ts, **/*.css
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.source=1.7
sonar.java.target=1.7
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
sonar.scm.provider=svn
sonar.links.scm=https://host/svnroot/project/trunk
sonar.verbose=true
```

PS: For the analysis of JAVA files it is done correctly.

Comment: the question is, how do you analyse the project -> which runner do you use, do you provide any settings per cli or per property file? and if so, what are does -> did you set your scanner maybe to just java?

Comment: I edited my question, but how can I know if i'm just analyzing the java files ?

Comment: There is a sonar property called 'sonar.language' (or something like that) which was used to specify which language is analyzed

Comment: `sonar.language` is deprecated since SQ 4.5, I use 6.7

Comment: you are right, but deprecated those not mean it is not used anymore :D it just means it will be removed. but anyways i posted an answer with a link

Comment: The `sonar.language` analysis property has been deprecated since version 4.5 (Sept. 2014), which was a long time ago. and using `sonar.language` automatically and immediately turns off multi-language analysis.

Comment: that is what is written in the docs. and maybe in your context make sense. but please be aware,i can only argue on the facts you are providing. in your question you never state that the analysis of the flex sources is working properly, nor that you are using a multi language build,you are just saying you want to show some analysis information, which is not showing. i do not have as much information at hand as you do. and hence that it is hard for me to verify where the problem is. and such a property can also lead to this behaviour. it was to much down the road,but can be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/ - this is not supported.

> Use SonarLint in Eclipse and detect issues in: Java, JavaScript,PHP,Python

Comment: I did not find any detail in the site except for the sentence which is written very clearly. thank you for your help